# SwiftUI properly localizes strings within Previews, but not when running the actual app

Tags: swift, xcode, swiftui

I have a `localizable.strings` file which renders localized strings within UIKit components just fine. It also renders strings in my SwiftUI previews just fine as well.

Within `localizable.strings`:

`"MY_STRING" = "PLEASE WORK!";`

```
struct MyView: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("MY_STRING")
    }
}

static var previews: some View {
    MyView()
        .environment(\.locale, .init(identifier: "en")) // This works when displayed in the canvas
}
```

However when I actually run the app in the simulator, it displays the literal string "MY_STRING".

Why would this work in Canvas Previews but not when running the app? Is there some special setting I'm missing?

Comment: Works fine with Xcode 13.4 / iOS 15.5. This is something in your project settings or... something. Try in new project from template. Try to clean/delete DerivedData/restart/rebuild.

Comment: In the Preview you specified "en" as the localization. Are you sure you real device or simulator are set to the right localization as well?

Comment: Correct, the simulator is by default in "en"